# Encountered a problem with strcat and strcpy in c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, string

So I was trying to use `strcat` and `strcpy` function in c++ in visual studio, and I have encountered an error and the compiler told me to use `strcat_s` and `strcpy_s`. When I used those functions, the errors were nullified and it gave me my output.

But when I defined a function `ex` and used `strcat_s` inside the `ex` function, it gave me an error, telling me `'strcat_s': function does not take 2 arguments

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void ex(char a[], char b[]) {
    cout << strcat_s(a, b);
}
int main() {
    string str;
    char a[20], b[20];
    cin >> a >> b;
    ex(a, b);
    cout << a <<" "<< b;
    cin >> str;
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

The [declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcat-s-wcscat-s-mbscat-s?view=msvc-160) says that strcat_s is an overloaded function with either 2 or 3 arguments:

```
template <size_t size>
errno_t strcat_s(
   char (&strDestination)[size],
   const char *strSource
);

errno_t strcat_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource
);
```

In you original program you used the first version, while in context of ex() the argument a[] is decayed to a pointer so it will try to use the 3 argument version.

Comment: Ok, but why did it work for this code

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 string str;
 char a[20], b[20];
 cin >> a >> b;
 strcat_s(a, b);
 cout << a <<" "<< b;
 return 0;
}

Comment: But thanks for answering mate, I'm new to programming so this might be a silly question